# Creating a copy of a workbook using open XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have an existing excel file on my local machine. I need to create a copy of it & save it some other location how can i do this using Open XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to use Open XML for this, it can be done easily with File.Copy, as shown below:

```
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            File.Copy(@"C:\whatever\original.xlsx", @"C:\whatever\new.xlsx");
        }
    }
}
```